# Рандом вплоть до десятых/сотых

Tags: php

Нужно получать случайное число в диапазоне от 00,00 до 100.00

Есть решение для данного вопроса?

Comment: Создайте исскуственно десятые и сотые из большего числа например, преобразовав во `float` и заюзав `round`

Comment: `echo round(rand(0, 10000)/100,2);`

Comment: @Ипатьев, думаете при делении на 100 целого числа будет больше 2х цифр после запятой?

Comment: @Visman, думает что больше и не требуется для ответа на вопрос

Comment: @Visman если не указать двойку, то будет до целого округляться

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, смеетесь? `echo rand(0, 10000)/100;`

Comment: @Visman похоже я действительно перестраховался. просто с этими плавающими точками никогда нельзя быть уверенным, что тебе вернет  1.9, а не 1,89999999999999999. Вместо rand лучше подойдет number_format()

Comment: Чтобы быть уверенным, поставьте запятую искуственно в заведомо большое число...

Comment: @Visman я говорил про `rand`......а простое деление не приведет к появлению лишних цифирок? точно? )

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, если эмулятор не врет, то ни чего лишнего не появится: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c5cebbfd6357874724f07708ad22e8c52055087f

Comment: @Ипатьев Пожалуйста, оставьте ответ, чтобы я отметил его, как правильный.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Спасибо за решение @Ипатьев. Слегка доработанный код:

```
return number_format(rand(0, 10000) / 100, 2, '.', '');
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/103019)

Comment: @Streletz правильный ответ был дан в комментариях.

Comment: Тогда есть смысл и поблагодарить в комментариях. Просто, согласно правилам сайта, поле "Ваш ответ" именно для ответов на вопросы. Ничего личного.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте это решение.

```
function random_float ($min,$max) {
   return ($min+lcg_value()*(abs($max-$min)));
}
```

Comment: Пример числа возвращаемого этой функцией --> `23.388192741654`

Comment: И? `round($var, 2);` Сложно?

Comment: Да, очень сложно!

Answer (score 2):

Код

```
echo rand(0, 10000)/100;
```

генерирует числа от 0 до 100, с максимум 2мя знаками после запятой.

Код с округлением

```
echo round(rand(0, 10000)/100,2);
```

избыточен. Тест тут http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c5cebbfd6357874724f07708ad22e8c52055087f